# Cakephp:: Auto submit form after validate $_GET parameters?

Tags: cakephp, forms, submit

When user submit from their mobile:

www.xxx.com/user?data1=name&data2=password

How do I submit to user controller automatically??

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a route that connects `/user` to some action in the UsersController.
2. In that action, grab the values from `$_GET`.

Passing along a username and password as GET variables seems like a bad idea though. Why can't you use normal POST requests?